# Position of words

Tags: grammaticality

Excuse me, may I know where is the location of McDonald's?

Excuse me, may I know where the location of McDonald's is?

Which of the above sentences is correct?

Comment: May I suggest an alternate?  "Excuse me, could you tell me where McDonald's is?"

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatical. Both are infelicitous, because "where the location of McDonald's is" is redundant, and people are more likely to say either "where McDonald's is" or "the location of McDonald's".

They are related by [Heavy component extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition), where the long component *the location of McDonald's* may optionally be moved to the end, leaving the much shorter element *is* close to its subject. [This is the third time I have mentioned this principle in an answer here in a few days!].